# Separate emails to internal and external users via workflow rule

Tags: email-alert, workflowrule

I have a workflow rule with one email alert which sends out an email to the Contact and internal users on case creation.

The problem is that both are receiving separate emails instead of one, i.e. one email is sent out to the contacts (external users) and another is sent out to the internal users. Both emails are same and the email sent out to the internal users is also addressed to the Case Contact.

We need it to send one email to all the users (internal and external) in the same email. This used to work I think till January.

I found the same issue faced by a user around 4 years ago. https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l3HOQAY

I reached out to Salesforce support but in the initial conversation, they said that there is no such setting which can switched on/off. They have raised a case now.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Email header for the internal users:

```
    Received: by 2002:a05:6a10:e906:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id gt6csp736927pxb;
        Thu, 10 Jun 2021 10:04:26 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJyBKqZB3SHSSLr6apV3UKEXrqAl1hcGWpsh7IurU+2W64bYnTDnjcF8P2MR0zWsf/z319/D
X-Received: by 2002:ac8:6f37:: with SMTP id i23mr624017qtv.376.1623344666605;
        Thu, 10 Jun 2021 10:04:26 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1623344666; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=FXqVv1Qa7cX6HlR1+YMvE2JMSNYjLgbWxnfqb7MpVXLxSdlbLSdVccgwJC8dsHzrlJ
         KoIC26EILC5hnceNuWjW2X3cwiE8GWQK/8lAfT9bd5FBO4cwUgqwxMD4Ajw+/kv9RTO/
         uY3JcNfm9TNhcJCLoquP2Fnn6u9znE592csGt5F4XTaqW3Z1D+bEjfC15ZQWiEz0oeoN
         PjRtHc2odbA+nzYi1JKO6bdUpA+SNkw+rb/5RwVyIj4ikj3PhEn+PVe1aPA7WTKnhWzo
         Pge0xrCqlCiZn8jmyNZ8t4TUd8C09uhJ9KeHsFer1KrzBAFrTqoHGMHogd2VWsm0R5eS
         qqLg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=mime-version:subject:message-id:to:from:date;
        bh=ALFILNsVxqW1PmyoeEHqOkKMRlzFdIGh4O3dVIvrVcA=;
        b=IGcIoJG6eD4UcS+m+WcaDsGJTd2G+vi2ySo/Cz7lrQBofc1GLyVAUGF1PtP8QEr5i/
         LEPvk4imSpUOsVD5y0haL66Xrpml25WoX2uvcNfpcqC3S4bn+RrvQv+nd8z/Vqs8mDbo
         kCFB/6wQJgkQ2pai15uHaxl46TIR0PCsO14mo1ydmdZ6JiyxmpNp8CRJ9lkSz8zD30gd
         +APtOP4zjPpNWTKRArAaqpBPdLl5TAzlNThDMqS3drgpce8tH+48o1RlVkXeYGxAHn6n
         9htvGp4AHXaC+EvdAgUtGV9LnGxNqFdtj65NE4QUnUJh5WJTQUczzIe6b2EjdH0T89cK
         Ex6w==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com designates 13.110.14.198 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com"
Return-Path: <cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com>
Received: from smtp07-ia2-sp3.mta.salesforce.com (smtp07-ia2-sp3.mta.salesforce.com. [13.110.14.198])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id c1si2378329qvn.142.2021.06.10.10.04.26
        for <s@internal.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 10 Jun 2021 10:04:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com designates 13.110.14.198 as permitted sender) client-ip=13.110.14.198;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com designates 13.110.14.198 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com"
Return-Path: <cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com>
Authentication-Results: mx4-ia2-sp3.mta.salesforce.com x-tls.subject="/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=salesforce.com, inc./OU=0:app;1:ia2;2:ia2-sp3;3:cs29;4:prod/CN=cs29-app2-2-ia2.ops.sfdc.net"; auth=pass (cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384)
Received: from [10.227.204.138] ([10.227.204.138:39254] helo=cs29-app2-2-ia2.ops.sfdc.net) by mx4-ia2-sp3.mta.salesforce.com (envelope-from <cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com>) (ecelerity 4.2.38.62368 r(Core:release/4.2.38.0)) with ESMTPS (cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 subject="/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=salesforce.com, inc./OU=0:app;1:ia2;2:ia2-sp3;3:cs29;4:prod/CN=cs29-app2-2-ia2.ops.sfdc.net") id 6A/C7-06136-A1642C06; Thu, 10 Jun 2021 17:04:26 +0000
Date: Thu, 10 Jun 2021 17:04:26 +0000 (GMT)
From: Support <support@internal.com>
To: "a@internal.com" <a@internal.com>, "s@internal.com" <s@internal.com>
Message-ID: <WvJPs000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000QUHWRD00yJ_UedAVTXuKTwWz2xmzpQ@sfdc.net>
Subject: Sandbox: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_724_794455252.1623344666224"
X-SFDC-LK: 00D0r00000018gA
X-SFDC-User: 0051W000005b9qt
X-Sender: postmaster@salesforce.com
X-mail_abuse_inquiries: http://www.salesforce.com/company/abuse.jsp
X-SFDC-TLS-NoRelay: 1
X-SFDC-Binding: 1WrIRBV94myi25uB
X-SFDC-EmailCategory: workflowActionAlert
X-SFDC-EntityId: 01W4000000093Bz
X-SFDC-Interface: internal

------=_Part_724_794455252.1623344666224
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


------=_Part_724_794455252.1623344666224
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Email header for the external user:

```
Received: by 2002:a05:6638:bd8:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id g24csp542075jad;
        Thu, 10 Jun 2021 10:04:26 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJytx49xHuU6F5TnlNo2TZjXJ/7WvtHC/prye5PT48HNvioFMTKGEQgjZpJ6T5AK6kVyDHeM
X-Received: by 2002:a0c:d610:: with SMTP id c16mr615547qvj.13.1623344666652;
        Thu, 10 Jun 2021 10:04:26 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1623344666; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=FIYDJgy8o5kFkWidioAfXX/yxYbXg1p5IKym/GhA/InQFX7DGUixjgZo7mrzSLVUod
         K+GSpO+PKZ7XThBYa4vsxG/b9y8gHMbOJ6E6PHmMmebe398sfyRikEwWiQEODSuuVI1R
         M7Eaglt1dwMr9RvrFdZdduDzVpjcpceIYATa2HwH7VhqycPH10XXCaZM0xSgWZwWVQvv
         VvSQ8DkCFApbBTsTmsyJJMgG82gTIu3KjJuRJvU6HuTP1swGjnpgyT6owMr7r4JzITgD
         Pw3qxeWhJUlEx3LbLgwWxA0URaCjCb4vU6qGl87fiQMHvVM2NZ6Qg6g1o+p7HLnxiWtI
         0E0A==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=mime-version:subject:message-id:to:from:date;
        bh=zipP0X/4xvUydRP15ZZUJeJgwM/Yy0F40hCskqK9IIY=;
        b=g3vklZHBZ0JaqApCHKK/28NNCrw47eJjnAjcs99e7Pr6ODtNS+2lyGwuwcj872ka4x
         aSQKE2MfmKtOor6GEMfasbmQME7XHLqdlr96eL3wEqu9Tt+qp86FQ7eWMPIKobXsffr0
         P4SY2TPokbhJ+ZlY0swLJsvNK6fZE4LsyVhrxXZ5qr4WMOXVHSEnfdocUc7h5lFox0DA
         RfT6MUj7cOEi69dv4eLCcAT82Auyzi/Sczm3LBInFuaq5tjdwzRbhfoPWD+H2M2fMJxZ
         uMWxWg2BqznLciIafg+PsH8hSQKaLnQd+XC+mSMnQC5bQraAqIpvAWPsFI8cQlnV6g8C
         T5eQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com designates 13.110.14.205 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com"
Return-Path: <cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com>
Received: from smtp14-ia2-sp3.mta.salesforce.com (smtp14-ia2-sp3.mta.salesforce.com. [13.110.14.205])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id v17si2400159qtx.89.2021.06.10.10.04.26
        for <s@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 10 Jun 2021 10:04:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com designates 13.110.14.205 as permitted sender) client-ip=13.110.14.205;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com designates 13.110.14.205 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com"
Return-Path: <cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com>
Authentication-Results: mx4-ia2-sp3.mta.salesforce.com x-tls.subject="/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=salesforce.com, inc./OU=0:app;1:ia2;2:ia2-sp3;3:cs29;4:prod/CN=cs29-app2-2-ia2.ops.sfdc.net"; auth=pass (cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384)
Received: from [10.227.204.138] ([10.227.204.138:39254] helo=cs29-app2-2-ia2.ops.sfdc.net) by mx4-ia2-sp3.mta.salesforce.com (envelope-from <cs29.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com>) (ecelerity 4.2.38.62368 r(Core:release/4.2.38.0)) with ESMTPS (cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 subject="/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=salesforce.com, inc./OU=0:app;1:ia2;2:ia2-sp3;3:cs29;4:prod/CN=cs29-app2-2-ia2.ops.sfdc.net") id 5B/C7-06136-A1642C06; Thu, 10 Jun 2021 17:04:26 +0000
Date: Thu, 10 Jun 2021 17:04:26 +0000 (GMT)
From: Support <support@internal.com>
To: "s@gmail.com" <s@gmail.com>
Message-ID: <WvJPs000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000QUHWRD00yMWtmepNRqeXBd3h4mEHFg@sfdc.net>
Subject: Sandbox: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_725_1998615414.1623344666389"
X-SFDC-LK: 00D0r00000018gA
X-SFDC-User: 0051W000005b9qt
X-Sender: postmaster@salesforce.com
X-mail_abuse_inquiries: http://www.salesforce.com/company/abuse.jsp
X-SFDC-TLS-NoRelay: 1
X-SFDC-Binding: 1WrIRBV94myi25uB
X-SFDC-EmailCategory: workflowActionAlert
X-SFDC-EntityId: 01W4000000093Bz
X-SFDC-Interface: internal

------=_Part_725_1998615414.1623344666389
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


------=_Part_725_1998615414.1623344666389
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Workflow email alert:

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that both emails are generated by the same workflow action? Perhaps the other email is generated by (for example) default Case settings. [Email logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&type=0) is one investigative tool. The other tool is the email message itself - it has extra headers that SF adds that record the origin of the email. Please update your question with details from email log and message headers and a screenshot of your workflow email alert action

Comment: @identigral Checked the email alert firing this email from the headers, they are same. Also updated the question as asked. Thank you.

Comment: Both emails are sent by the same workflow (`X-SFDC-EntityId` header is the workflow id). Can't see a reason why it would send a separate email, perhaps it is a bug. SF support is the right channel for solving this.

Comment: Thank you @identigral I thought so too. Let's see what they say about this.

Comment: @identigral I also tried testing with other workflow rules on Case and they are also sending separate emails. I tested for another object and they are sending single email to the external and internal users. Not sure what is happening. I have a meeting with them today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use standard Contact Email field instead of Related Contact lookup field. Related contact field only works for the Contacts not enabled as Community users, whereas email field works for Community enabled and not enabled users both.

The change is not recent and was apparently released in Summer'15. I am not sure how this used to work till now though. I am trying to find some documentations on such behaviour but unable to. I have asked Salesforce Support to provide the link or create one, if not available.